# Initially hiding div with style set to display:block

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

I'm using CSS style `display:block` and `none` for hiding a `div` based on a condition: 
If facebook has been blocked display `fb_Blockedwizard` else display `fb_wizard`.

When I am loading or refreshing the page the `div fb_Blockedwizard` is displayed for a few second then the `div` gets hidden.

**I need to hide the `div` during the load or refresh of the page**

Below is the code which I'm using:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    hideFbBlockedwizard();
    hidefbwizard();
    var callbackOnSuccess = function(src) {
      hideFbBlockedwizard();
      showwizard();
      return false;
    };
    var callbackOnFailure = function(src) {
      hidefbwizard();
      showFbBlockedwizard();
    };
    checkAvailability("http://www.facebook.com/favicon.ico", 
      callbackOnSuccess,callbackOnFailure);
  });

  function  showFbBlockedwizard() {
    document.getElementById('fb_Blockedwizard').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';
  }   

  function hideFbBlockedwizard() {  
    document.getElementById('fb_Blockedwizard').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none';
  }

  function checkAvailability(src, callbackSuccess, callbackFailure) {
    $("<img/>").attr("src", src).load(function() {
      callbackSuccess(src);     
  }).error(function() {
    callbackFailure(src);
  });
}

function showwizard() {
  document.getElementById('fb_Blockedwizard').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('fb_wizard').style.display='block';
  document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';    
}
```

Here my CSS:

```
.white_content {
        /*display: none;*/
        display:none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 25%;
        left: 25%;
        width: 46%;
        height: 37%;
        padding: 16px;
        border: 16px solid #999;
        background-color: white;
        z-index:1002;
        overflow: auto;
}
.white_content1 {
        display:none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 13%;
        left: 18%;
        width: 60%;
        height: 63%;
        padding: 16px;
        border: 16px solid #999;
        background-color: white;
        z-index:1002;
        overflow: auto;
}
```

Here my PHP:

```
  <div id="fb_wizard" class="white_content">
  <?php include  'fb_blocked.php'; ?>
  </div>
  <div id="fb_Blockedwizard" class="white_content1">
         <?php include  'fb_blocked_email.php'; ?> </div>
```

Comment: set the blocks style to none in the html, then it wont appear before the js gets to it

Comment: @Dagon : i have set  display:none; in css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `fb_Blockedwizard` part of your layout? If so then give it directly the style `display:none` within HTML/CSS. Set it to `display:block` per javascript.

Comment: i have set display:none; in css

Comment: You have to assure that this style is initially assigned to the html element. Without any javascript interaction. Then the browser won't show it up at the first rendering. When your javascript kicks in you can check if you want to display that element. If so change the style to `display:block`.